# Regarding left-to-right minima

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, permutations

Let $\rho$ be a permutation on $[1,n]$ and $l_i$ be the number of left-to-right minima in $\rho_{i\ldots n}$, I know that for a random permutation $E[l_1] = H_n$ (the $n$-th Harmonic number) but is the value $E[max(l_1, l_2, \ldots, l_n)]$ known ?  If not, what would be a good direction to compute or simply upper-bound it ?  I suspect it is $\mathcal{O}(H_n)$.

Comment: By $\rho_{i...n}$, you mean the suffix of the permutation, $j \mapsto \rho(j)$ for $i \le j \le n$?

Comment: Yes, I mean that.

Answer (score 2):

If you ignore the relationships between the $l_i$, you can still use the union bound to get an upper bound on the probability that the maximum is at least $x$ that is off by at most a factor of $n$, and then you can use this to show the expected value of the maximum is $H_n(1+o(1))$.

Since each $l_i$ is a sum of Bernoulli random variables, the indicators of positions of potential minima, we can use [Hoeffding's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) for sums of bounded random variables. The average value of $l_i$ is $H_{n-i+1}$. It is a sum of $n-i+1$ Bernoulli random variables, so for $x \ge 0$, $P[l_i - H_{n-i+1} \gt t] \le \exp(-2(n-i+1)t^2)$, or for $i'=n-i+1$, $P[l_{i'} - h_i \gt t] \le \exp(-2 i t^2)$. Choose any $\epsilon \gt 0$.

$$\begin{eqnarray} E[\max(l_1,...,l_n)] & \le & (1+\epsilon)H_n + \sum_{x \gt (1+ \epsilon)H_n} P(\max(l_1,...,l_n) \gt x) \newline & \le & (1+\epsilon)H_n + \sum_{x \gt (1+\epsilon)H_n} \sum _{i=1}^n P(l_i \gt x) \newline & \le & (1+\epsilon)H_n + \sum_{x \gt (1+\epsilon)H_n} \sum _{i=1}^n \exp(-2 (n-i+1)(x-H_{n-i+1})^2) \newline & = & (1+\epsilon)H_n + \sum_{x \gt (1+\epsilon)H_n} \sum _{i=1}^n \exp(-2 i(x-H_{i})^2) \end{eqnarray}$$

We can change the order of summation and estimate very coarsely

$$\begin{eqnarray}\sum_{x \gt (1+\epsilon)H_n} \exp (-2i(x-H_i)^2) & \le & \sum_{x \ge 0} \exp(-2i(x+(1+\epsilon)H_n-H_i)^2) \newline & \le & \sum_{x \ge 0} \exp(-2(x+\epsilon H_n)^2) \newline & \le & \exp(-2\epsilon^2 H_n^2) \frac{1}{1-\exp(-2(2\epsilon H_n+1))}\end{eqnarray}$$

by comparison with a geometric series with the same first two terms. Since $H_n \gt \log n$,

$$ \begin{eqnarray} & & &\le &\exp(-2 \epsilon^2 (\log n)^2) \frac{1}{1- \exp (-4 \epsilon H_n - 2)} \newline & & &\le & \exp(-2 \epsilon^2 (\log n)^2) \frac{1}{1- \exp (- 2)} \newline & & &\le& 2 \exp(-2 \epsilon^2 (\log n)^2) \newline & & & \le & 2 n^{-2 \epsilon^2 \log n} \end{eqnarray}$$

This estimate doesn't depend on $i$.

$$\begin{eqnarray} E[\max(l_1,...,l_n)] & \le & (1+\epsilon) H_n + \sum_{i=1}^n 2 n^{-2 \epsilon^2 \log n} \newline &=& (1+\epsilon)H_n + 2n^{-2 \epsilon^2\log n + 1} \newline & = & (1+\epsilon)H_n + o(1).\end{eqnarray} $$

So, $E[\max(l_1,...l_n)] \sim H_n$. The estimates here were coarse, and while they could be improved to estimate the difference $ E[\max(l_1,...l_n)] - H_n$, using some of the dependencies between the $\lbrace l_i \rbrace$ should be necessary to get the true order.

Comment: Thank you.  The only (trivial?) part I don't get is $E[max(l_i)] \leq (1+\epsilon)H_n + ...$

Comment: I used two steps there. First, there is a standard trick that comes from rewriting a non-negative integer-valued random variable $M$ as a sum of indicators of whether the random variable is at least n. $M = Z_1 + Z_2 + ...$ so $E[M] = E[Z_1 + Z_2 + ...] = E[Z_1] + E[Z_2] + ... = P(Z_1=1) + P(Z_2=1) + ...$. Let $h= \lfloor 1+\epsilon H_n \rfloor, M = \max(h,\max(l_1,...,l_n)).$ Then $M = h + 1_{\{M \ge h+1\}} + 1_{\{M \ge h+2\}} + ...$ so $E[\max(l_1,...,l_n)] \le E[M] = h + P(M \ge h+1) + P(M \ge h+2) + ...$.

Comment: Second, I used the union bound. For the max of $l_1, ..., l_n$ to be at least $x$, at least one of them must be, so the probability that the max is at least $x$ is at most the sum of the probabilities that each $l_i$ is at least $x$.